# WARNING: More than 10 instances of ADBannerView or ADInterstitialView currently exist

Tags: objective-c, ios8.1, adbannerview

I have a iPad app with 2 view controllers; 1st one is for the UI, the 2nd for a view which displays help from a UIWebView.  When I go back and forth 10 times between view controllers, I get the message in the title above on *exactly* the 10th time returning to the first VC.

This is my code in VC #1:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated  {

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)];

_adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, 320, 50)];
_adBanner.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:adView];
}


- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated  {

[_adBanner removeFromSuperview];
_adBanner.delegate = nil;
_adBanner = nil;

}


- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner  {

if (!_bannerIsVisible)  {

    // If banner isn't part of view hierarchy, add it
    if (_adBanner.superview == nil)
        [self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
    //        }

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

    // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    _bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}


- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error  {

NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad");

if (_bannerIsVisible)  {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

    // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    _bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

I know why, just don't know how to fix it.  Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: what is `adView` and why do you create it then appear to do nothing with it ever again. also you should be calling `[super viewWillDisappear:]`

Comment: Please re-write your comment as an Answer -- I removed *adView* and made *_adBanner* the subView... works like a charm now!  Thank you for your time, I appreciate it!  SD

Answer (score 0):

You create an instance of `ADBannerView` in `viewDidAppear` and assign it to `adView` You don't appear do anything with this and more relevantly don't discard it in `viewWillDisappear` so each time you pop back to this view controller the previous instance is orphaned when you cycle through `viewDidAppear`.

Also possibly another issue is that you are not calling `[super viewWillDisappear:]` in your `viewWillDisappear` method.